# Operator+ overloading return value to Operator=

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm trying to return the result of operator+ to operator= but am getting a bogus value when returning *this in operator =; when calling rhs and accessing its functions the values are correct, but operator = is not sending out a copy of the class whats wrong?

```
          VecXd& operator=(const VecXd &rhs)
           { 

              cout << rhs.vecArr[0] << " " << rhs.vecArr[1] << " " << rhs.vecArr[2] << " " << endl;
              return *this;    
           }


    VecXd& operator+(const VecXd& rhs){
    VecXd& result = *this;
      cout << "TEST FOR DIMENSION-> " << dimension << endl;
   if(result.dimension == rhs.dimension) //dimension level check
   { 

        for(int i = 0; i < rhs.dimension; i++)
      {
        result.vecArr[i] += rhs.vecArr[i];
        cout << result.vecArr[i] << " our new value" << endl;                 
      } 
      cout << result << " result test!"  << endl;

      return result;
   }
   else{
      cout << "Dimensions do not match!!! Error!" << endl;    
      }
```

}

Help? thank you!

Comment: Just skimming your code, maybe you want `VecXd &result = *this;` instead of `VecXd result = *this;`?

Comment: I would also suggest looking at using assertions or exceptions instead of your `if (dimension == rhs.dimension)` check.  If the code skips to else, the function no longer returns a value.

Comment: I implemented what you said, and noticed that the value operator= takes in (const VecXd& rhs) gives me the correct values when I access its functions using rhs. but returning from operator= is not returning the class?

Comment: Declaring `result` like this: `VecXd &result = *this;` would be right if you were implementing the += operator, but you are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shold not return a reference to `result`. `result` is a local variable, and goes out of scope when exiting the method. You most likely want to return a copy of `result`, so change your operator return type:

```
VecXd operator+(const VecXd& rhs) const
```

This will return a value of type `VecXd` and not a reference.

Oh, and since you are implementing the + operator, and not the += operator, you probably want to change this:

```
vecArr[i] += rhs.vecArr[i];
```

to this as well:

```
result.vecArr[i] = vecArr[i] + rhs.vecArr[i];
```

And there is probably no need to initialize `result` using `*this`

Comment: This is an answer to your question before you changed your example code. Now you have ended up implementing the += operator while calling it the + operator. Who ever reads your code or uses your class will hate you :-p